# Content Restriction Ideas

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, security

I was trying to do subscription system which is only for registered user. Till registration stage, I am okie. But I don't want user to share their username and password with others because of the paid content. How can i prevent ?

1. Check with IP, but what if they are on dynamic IP ? Using proxy ?
2. Store cookies can change ?

Can anyone please kindly suggest how can i prevent ? I know there's no 100% bullet proof, but somehow, alittle bit tight security system.

Language will be with php, mysql, javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend heuristics based approach -- if you detect something suspicious (eg. user connecting from many different IP-s) then you log this and this increments some counter in users's record, if the counter grows big enough, then you get notification and decide what to do.

It won't eliminate all cases of account sharing but hints you the problem users.

Comment: yeap, log IP is in my part of plan. But I want tight security than this. Like logging by IP and moderating is less automation process. Moderator have to check most of the time for suspicious activity. I want some automation process that we can prevent from sharing the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

when your content is payed content, tell the users that they have to enter ther credit card informations every 10th login. I think this will stop them to share account. (When CC informations are wrong, the account will be closed).

Other idea: Limit the Sessions for one user to 2 - 3. They will think twice to share their credentials if they are not able to login when their friends are connected.

Comment: Cool, the first idea i like it, but second one, limit the sessions for one user to 2-3, i doesn't understand. It does mean shorter session time ?

Comment: and, storing their credit card information is quite senstive. If we got hijack the sql, we are goner. Any idea ?

Comment: i mean only allow 1 login per user at the same time

Comment: yeap, still they can share their login.